# How can I create multiple event emmiters with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io and twit module.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('get:tweet', function (data) {
    var twit = new Twit({
        consumer_key: config.get('twitter:consumer_key'),
        consumer_secret: config.get('twitter:consumer_secret'),
        access_token: config.get('twitter:access_token'),
        access_token_secret: config.get('twitter:access_token_secret')
    });
    twit.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '#' + data.hashtag})
        .on('tweet', function (tweet) {
            socket.emit('test', {tweet: tweet, id: data.guid});
        });
});
```

});

But if I create another client, then First client doesn't give emit value.

How should I create a dynamic twit emitter?